# jquery tabs refresh creates dummy div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am rendering HTML inside Sharepoint in an iframe. For rendering HTML I am trying to add a tab using jquery tabs. 
Please see the code for adding tab.

```js
$("<li><a href='#G1'>G1</a></li>").appendTo("#tabs > ul");
$("<div id='G1'style='display:block;'>G1</div>").appendTo("#tabs");
$.fn.fetchTabID = function(id) {
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", $('#G1').index() - 1);
};
$("#tabs").tabs('refresh');
$("#tabs").fetchTabID(tabid);
```

While calling `$("#tabs").tabs('refresh')`, the div `G1` is added as a normal div instead of tab.The issue was only when MDS is enabled in this Sharepoint site.Any help appreciated.

[Please see this image for HTML at the time of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCqE8.png)
[image: HTML at the time of issue]

[Please see this image for HTML when its working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLtsh.png)
[image: HTML when its working]

I am using jQuery version: 1.11.3 and Sharepoint 2013

**Update:** While I tested this in Chrome its working fine. I got the issue in IE 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the root cause of the issue. While calling the 'refresh' method of tabs, its internally checking whether the request for creating tab is a remote tab or tab within the same page. For this purpose, they check it by matching the url of added anchor tag and document.url. Since the anchor tag is inside the iframe, the url will be of the page which is called inside iframe. When MDS is enabled the document url will contain '/_layouts/15/start.aspx#'. So the urls doesn't match. The 'refresh' method would not consider the added anchor tag for tab hence it will create new div.

Solution: i have overridden the function of jquery tabs(function name is '_isLocal') which is used for checking the urls.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is being inserted exactly as you define it. If this is unexpected, then the magic sauce introduced by the tabs library isn't coming through, perhaps because it's being held back by the minimal download strategy.

You could either try to emulate whatever crazy stuff the tabs library is doing for you behind the scenes, or figure out why the MDS is stomping on the library.

It looks like you could simply specify the appropriate class names that you want the div to have when you add it to the page.

Instead of:

```
$("<div id='G1'style='display:block;'>G1</div>").appendTo("#tabs");
```

You can do:

```
$("<div id='G1' class='ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom'>G1</div>").appendTo("#tabs");
```

Comment: My div has been appended to tabs , but I am expecting the added div as a tab. On latest jquery versions there is no built in method for adding tab as they deprecated 'add' method in tabs. I am afraid above code is the only method for adding tabs. Also I cant remove the functionality of tabs and its essential for me.

Comment: Also tried the code given above and It doesn't help.